# Determine the convergence of the following series

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, divergent-series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty {3^{k\ln k} \over {k^k}}$$

I need to determine the convergence of this series. I know it diverges, but how do I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Root test to get $$\lim_{k\to+\infty}(\frac{3^{k\ln k}}{k^k})^{1/k}=\lim_{k\to+\infty}\frac{3^{\ln k}}{k}=\lim_{k\to+\infty}(\frac{3}{e})^{\ln k}=+\infty>1$$ so on ...
If you change $3$ with $2$ then it is convergent; interesting!

Comment: Very good indeed. +1

Comment: How do you get to the ${({3\over e})}^{lnk}$?

Comment: @Username19 What is $e^{\ln k}$?

Comment: K! Very clever indeed!